# Manually Coding Breusch-Pagan Test in SAS

Tags: sas

Does following code correctly execute the Breusch-Pagan test, and if not, what is the error?

```
proc reg data = mydataset;
TITLE 1 "The following is the Breusch-Pagan test for Constant Variance";
model Y = X1;
output out = newdataset r = resid;
run;

data BP;
set newdataset;
e2 = log10(resid*resid);
run;

proc reg data = BP;
model e2 = X1;   * The p-value of the beta-coefficient for X1 is the BP test p-value;
run;
```

I was told to run the test this way, but it is producing unexpected results. I'd like some third-party validation. (I'm aware that PROC Model has a built-in Breusch-Pagan test. That is not my question.)

Answer (score 0):

SAS uses a modified version of the Breusch-Pagan test that relaxes (but doesn't eliminate) normality assumptions. The way in which you are testing it is not exactly the same way that SAS is doing it. SAS's version of the B-P test and the equation for the test statistic is documented on their website.

> This is a modified version of the Breusch-Pagan test, which is less sensitive to the assumption of normality than the original test (Greene 1993, p. 395).

[Source](https://go.documentation.sas.com/?cdcId=pgmsascdc&cdcVersion=9.4_3.4&docsetId=etsug&docsetTarget=etsug_model_sect121.htm&locale=en)

Comment: I'm not asking whether the above code is imitating SAS's internal code. I'm simply asking whether the code is executing the B-P test in a valid way, or if it is erroneous. I'm asking because 1) the code does not replicate the B-P test in the way I have read it theoretically explained and 2) when I use the code it is indicating that my data has non-constant variance when even a brief glance shows that it very obviously does have constant variance.

Comment: Stack Overflow is normally more for code help, and this question would be better answered on Cross Validated. To answer your question, this is not a valid way to calculate the B-P test statistic. Check this out here on how to calculate it correctly with proc reg: http://lipas.uwasa.fi/~sjp/Teaching/ecm/sas/ex72.html

Comment: Thank you for that link. I see that the error is in taking the log of the squared residual. When I remove that, I get the expected result. I'm not sure why the person who gave me to code though the logarithm is necessary...

Comment: Great question. I was curious why they didn't log both sides. I wonder if you'd get the same answer.